# Вывод массива на страницу

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня массив ниже. Можно ли из него сделать таблицу, чтобы вывести его на страницу, через document.write? К примеру, заголовок cars. 
в первой колонке, название авто(bmv, reno, audi), во второй(model), третьей(year), а в четвертой что останется. И покрасить колонки в разные цвета.

```
var cars = {
    "bmv": {
        model: "X5",
        year: 2002,
        km: 10000
    },

    "reno": {
        model: "Logan",
        year: 2010,
        color: "red"
    },

    "audi": {
        model: "A8",
        year: 2009,
    }
};
```

Comment: Можно. *(9 символов нужно...)*

Comment: мне помогли доделать [вот здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/747879) и получилось [вот так](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PoPoVap?editors=1010)

Comment: @MaximLensky код немного устарел, посмотри мой ответ ниже (*и исправь молю господа бога если still используешь это где-то* :) )

Comment: @MaximLensky в смысле - es6 вышел в 2015 году

Comment: @MaximLensky я про песочницу и говорю..

Comment: @MaximLensky сравни пожалуйста мой код из ответа, с [песочечкой](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PoPoVap) (еще 31 строка = *глазкиплакплак*, имхо)

Comment: @MaximLensky (я не про jq), тебя не смущает, что ты пушишь собирательные данные каждую итерацию?

Comment: @MaximLensky я не обновляю данные каждую итерацию и я не хочу продолжать этот монолог

Comment: @MaximLensky открой [песочку](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PoPoVap), подумай, что если ты 31 и 32 строки поменяешь местами

Во вторых, строки 22-28, обращение к пелеменной происходит 6 раз, когда в моём коде 1, сейчас разница в долях сек, а если `cars` будет с большим размером

Comment: @MaximLensky да, +если уж *придираться*, то остался **var**. По итогу получился мой код из ответа без jq и заголовка

Comment: Извините задумался, общаюсь сам с собой, бывает

Comment: @Vadim я не понял тебя щас\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про строку после `summ+=` [тута](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/#9)

Приклажываю код, в нём по тз - `summ2`, и раздельно

```js
const cars = {
    'bmv': {
        model: 'X5',
        year: 2002,
        km: 10000
    },
    
    'reno': {
        model: 'Logan',
        year: 2010,
        color: 'red'
    },
    
    'audi': {
        model: 'A8',
        year: 2009,
    }
};

let summ = '<tr><td>name</td><td>model</td><td>year</td><td>left</td></tr>';
for(let car in cars){
    summ += `<tr>
        <td style="background:lightgrey;">${car}</td>
        <td>${cars[car].model}</td>
        <td>${cars[car].year ? cars[car].year : ''}</td>
        <td>${cars[car].color ? cars[car].color : (cars[car].km ? cars[car].km : '')}</td>
    </tr>`;
}

let summ2 = '<tr><td>name</td><td>model</td><td>year</td><td>color</td><td>mileage</td></tr>';
for(let car in cars){
    summ2 += `<tr>
        <td>${car}</td>
        <td class="model">${cars[car].model}</td>
        <td>${cars[car].year ? cars[car].year : ''}</td>
        <td>${cars[car].color ? cars[car].color : ''}</td>
        <td>${cars[car].km ? cars[car].km : ''}</td>
    </tr>`;
}

console.log(summ, summ2);
$('.table').html(summ);
$('.table2').html(summ2);
```

```css
.model{background:darkgrey;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border></table>
<table class="table2" border></table>
```